# Prevenir gesto de deslizamiento en un ViewPager en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

¿Cómo se puede desactivar el deslizamiento de páginas de un `ViewPage` cuando se realiza un gesto `swipe`?

Answer (score 1):

Para deshabilitar-lo puedes poner ésto:

```
 final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.Pager); 
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {         
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        { 
           return true; 
        }
     });
```

Haz eso mismo en  `onInterceptTouchEvent (event MotionEvent)`.

Sino he encontrado una duda parecida en StackOverflow en inglés, sigue esos pasos :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s

[java](/questions/tagged/java)[android](/questions/tagged/android)

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que un elemento dentro del ViewPager no tenga habilitado el desplazamiento, puedes tomar la referencia del contenedor padre que contiene tu ViewPager, por ejemplo un layout puedes desabilitarlo de esta forma:

```
  myLinearlayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Esto suponiendo estas dentro de un fragmento, yo considero que es lo que tiene mayor uso dado el uso de fragmentos en las aplicaciones.

Si se realiza esto dentro de un `ViewPager` tendrías que sobreescribir los eventos     `onTouchEvent` y `onInterceptTouchEvent`:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }    
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }    
        return false;
    }
```